# Does JMeter scripts actually creates records in database

Tags: database, performance, jmeter, performance-testing, response-time

Let's say I run a recorded script for 'New User Registration' function of a web site to evaluate the response time for entire scenario. When I run the recorded script from JMeter, for each registration script, is there a new user record getting created in the application database ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you record registration and correlate it (meaning you create a valid unique name for every request) you will create a real user in your environment.

JMeter is simulating a real scenario which effect your environment.

That is part of the reason JMeter will be executed in different environment than production (as stage)

Answer (score 0):

Well-behaved JMeter script must represent a real user using a real browser as close as it is possible.

- Browsers execute [HTTP requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) and render the response
- JMeter executes the same HTTP requests but doesn't render the response, instead it records [performance metrics](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420665-Performance-Metrics-for-Websites-Performance-Metrics-for-Websites) like response time, connect time, latency, throughput, etc.

[HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) is a [stateful protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol#Stacking_of_stateless_and_stateful_protocol_layers) therefore given you execute the same request you will get the same response. So if there are no mistakes in your script it either should create a new user or fail due to non-unique username error.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if your script accurately represents the full set of data flows associated with the business process, "New User Registration," then the end state of that process should be identical to that of the user behavior so modeled.

A record will be created in the database.  If not, then your user is not accurate in its behavior